# Do I need to call SaveChanges when using EFCore.BulkExtensions

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, ef-core-2.0

I started using EFCore.BulkExtensions for ef bulk operations, and it is working very nice.

(see https://github.com/borisdj/EFCore.BulkExtensions/)

do I need to call also to SaveChanges:

```
        using (var db = new ReportingContext())
        {
            db.BulkInsertOrUpdate(entities);
            db.SaveChanges();
        }
```

or this is good enough?

```
        using (var db = new ReportingContext())
        {
            db.BulkInsertOrUpdate(entities);
        }
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The page from the link contains the following

> Under the hood uses [SqlBulkCopy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlbulkcopy?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2) for Insert, for Update/Delete combines BulkInsert with raw Sql [MERGE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/merge-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) (MsSQL 2008+).

So the answer is no, you don't need to call `SaveChanges` because EFCore.BulkExtensions works directly with the database (SqlServer). The entities you pass may not even be attached (tracked) to the context. It uses the context just to get entity model metadata and connection/transaction info.